# Mulch that doesn't wash away

Tags: mulch

I have mulch from last year that seems to wash a way a lot on my slight hill. There are other homes I've seen that have a similar slope but their mulch doesn't appear to wash away. The mulch I got was the [Home Depot Earthgro brown mulch](https://www.google.com/shopping/product/16727797026515387701?lsf=seller:8740,store:2803178092106296528&prds=oid:10718331090859726415&q=home%20depot%20brown%20mulch&hl=en&ei=nuGeWbCSEonJmwGk8b94&mid=s4cGCCfgL%7Cdc_mtid_8903jx325196_pcrid_107016508288_pkw__pmt__product_202585785_slid_&lsft=gclid:EAIaIQobChMIgvursYnw1QIV242zCh1pbAEqEAQYASABEgJ0ePD_BwE) which is sort of larger in size. I have seen some mulches at landscape stores that are much more finely chopped. When I re-mulch in May 2018, Is it better to get more finely chopped mulch and pack it down and that may help with preventing it from washing away?

Comment: You just have to go check your local soil vendors for the mulch I keep trying to get people to use.  I am so serious. Call your city utility that collects our poop!  If they are decomposing via Federal standards I envy you!  This is GOLD. No weed seeds.  No pesticide residues.  Fine fine texture.  Smells wonderful! Dark taupe. Forget pulling up weeds. Just dump on top of your plant beds 2". No weeds.  This stuff FEEDS your soil which your plants need. Also has nitrogen for an amazing perk up of all your plants.  Please check this out.  Not any more expensive than bark chips.

Comment: @stormy I believe there are chemical residues in most humanure/poop, isn't that true? Perhaps from pharmaceuticals.

Comment: Yes, and that is their only problem.  Heavy metals.  But truth be told most municipal waters contain more.  This is why it is not for edibles.  At the rate we humans are dumping fluoride, not filtering heavy metals, nuking our oceans and fish, cloud seeding (chemtrails using primarily heavy metals)...check out the patents since 1920's.  Your eyebrows will go up when you read the list of 'seeding' material to make clouds...water vapor.  You know, the number one 'green house' gas!  Of topic, I know.  But this dang mulch was the ONLY mulch I would use for my clients landscapes as well as my own.

Comment: Seeding clouds is one thing, but chemtrails - come on stormy: http://www.smithsonianmag.com/smart-news/science-officially-debunks-chemtrails-conspiracy-live-180960139/

Answer (score 3):

Shredded bark or wood mulch is a good choice especially if it has a mixture of sizes.  These pieces can tangle and hold each other down.  Hardwoods tend to be heavier and stay in place better than softwoods.

If you are using any fabric or plastic under the mulch this will create a flat surface which the mulch can slide off easily.  Instead use layers of mulch to reduce weeds.

Edging with a material that is several inches high like wood, stone or bricks can create a barrier that will hold mulch where it belongs.  You can also create a small trench that will capture mulch so it can be raked back onto the bed.

It would be labor intensive but if your slope is extreme perhaps you could use terraces to create flat beds instead of sloped beds.

Answer (score 1):

Non decomposed bark chips float off the beds during downpours.  My answer to this is the little trench I always use at the bottom of the beds between the bed and lawn.  The mulch collects and is easily thrown back up onto the beds.  Use a line trimmer for the edge of your lawn and you've got beauty.  Since you are doing all this work, you should be making your lawn edges look professional.
[image: picture of Gro-Co mulch]

[image: Lawn edges]

The beauty of a lawn is in the edges. That is what the eye sees firstus and mostus.  The rule is to make a curve with a consistent radius.  Doesn't matter what radius just keep the curve consistent until needing to reverse the curve.  Then keep that radius consistent until needing to go the other way.  I always make a 6inch by 6inch trench between beds and lawns throwing the soil up on the bed or over an errant weed in the back of the bed.  Once a year?  The sides of this trench are sloped.  This defines the edge, greatly helps to keep mulch on beds in place yet doesn't distract like a concrete curb edge does.  Less expensive as well.  I also do the 'peninsula' thing to create mystery.  You don't want to see the entire yard from the door or window of your home.  Why go outside?  This makes one want to walk through the yard.  I even use 'screens' of lumber to enhance this trick and take up less space in a small yard.

Please send a picture of this slope. You will have to renew this mulch every other year because it is being eaten and mixed into your existing soil.  So cool. My computer kinda wigged out and there might be a few odd transitions here.  I'll fix in a bit.